# arithmetic del Pezzo surfaces in comparison with del Pezzo surfaces over a field

Tags: reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, schemes, algebraic-surfaces, fano-varieties

A del Pezzo surface is a smooth, 2-dimensional projective variety $X$ with ample anticanonical divisor, i.e. a 2-dimensional Fano variety.

I am interested in the arithmetic analogue, a 2-dimensional projective scheme $X$ with a relative 1-dimensional morphism to a Dedekind scheme $X \to S$, such that the anticanonical divisor is ample.

It would be sensible to require $X$ to be a regular scheme, but I would prefer not to require the structure morphism to $S$ to be smooth, as I would like to coexist peacefully with fibers of bad reduction.

I am typically thinking of $S = \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}), \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}_p), \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_q[t]), \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{F}_q}$, or finite extensions.

**Question**: In what way are such objects analogous (or not) to del Pezzo surfaces over a field?
By this I mean in terms of their intrinsic properties, and in how they may be distinguished from other surfaces in their respective area. Classical del Pezzo surfaces are quite special.

Is there a specific name for such schemes? Some good references to read about them?

I hoped to find something in Qing Liu's nice book, but have not found anything yet.

Comment: Since $X \to S$ is of relative dimension $1$, a smooth fibre must be a $\mathbf P^1$ if the relative anticanonical is ample. So this is more analogous to a ruled surface than a del Pezzo...

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Thanks. How does one prove this? I suspected the fibers would generally be simple, and perhaps you're right that a ruled surface is the better analogy. However I am particularly interested in the del Pezzo/Fano condition on the anticanonical bundle, as well as in the nonsmooth fibers, where the bulk of the action lies.

Comment: Do you know Alessio Corti's paper "Del Pezzo surfaces over Dedekind schemes"? https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9505036.pdf

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi No, I don't. Thank you, it does look interesting, but it appears to me to be one dimension too large for me. Is there a straightforward relationship? Of note is that the special fiber, an arithmetic surface, will never be mixed characteristic, which excludes the cases of most interest to me.